# How to not reset form values in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using `Django-admin` for inserting data. But when I submit, the form resets values, so I need to insert some of the fields again. Is it possible not to reset some of the field values?[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the some initial value in your form's initialized:

`models.charField(default="x")`

or

`models.charField(initial= "x")`

Comment: Hey, thank you for an answer, but it is not what I am looking for, I need a more dynamic approach